# Invisible graphs cause report to slow

Tags: graph, reporting-services

I have a report with a parameter where the end user chooses a practice name that corresponds to a group of people. Most of these groups have fewer than 10 people, but a small number of them have as many as 150. When there are more than 15 people in a given group, they want separate graphs, each with no more than 15 people. So for most of the groups, we only need one graph. For a few, we need a lot of graphs.

Behind the scenes, I created a graph for each multiple of 15 people, and set them to only be visible if there are actually that many people in the group. This does what I need it to, but it makes the report super slow. As close as I can tell, behind the scenes when an end user runs the report it's still somehow rendering the hidden graphs and slowing it all to heck. ([I did find this link which I think suggests this is a known bug.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b53f8bd-bf67-43ef-89ad-99730f7b55c6/charts-slow-report-rendering-to-a-crawl?forum=sqlreportingservices)

I need to have one report where the end user selects the practice name, so I can't make two reports, "My practice is normal" and "My practice is ginormous". I thought maybe I could make a conditional sub-report split into those two reports based on the practice name parameter, but that doesn't appear to be possible; you can play around with visibility but I'm guessing that will still cause the invisible graph rendering problem and not help my speed.

Are there any other cool tips I can try to speed up my report, or is this just a case of too many graphs spoiling the broth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to generate a group number for every 15 people and then use a list control to repeat the chart for each group.

Here's a very quick example of this in action. I just used some sample data from one of the Adventure Works sample database.

Here's my query that returns every person in each selected department. Note that I have commented out the `DELCARE`s as these were just in there for testing.

```
--DECLARE @Department varchar(50) = ''
--DECLARE @chartMax int = 5
SELECT 
    GroupName, v.Department, v.FirstName, v.LastName
    , ChartGroup = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY LastName, FirstName)-1) / @chartMax -- calc which chart number the person belongs to
    , Salary = ((ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100) * 500) + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000) + 10000 -- Just some random number to plot
  FROM [HumanResources].[vEmployeeDepartment] v
  WHERE Department IN (@Department) 
  ORDER BY Department
```

The key bit is the `ChartGroup` column

```
ChartGroup = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY LastName, FirstName)-1) / @chartMax
```

This will give the first 5 rows in each department a ChartGroup of 0 the next 15 1 and so on. I used 5 rather than 15 just so it's easier to demo.

Here's the dataset results

[image]

Now, in your report, add a List, set it's dataset property to your dataset containing your main data (the query above in my case).

Now edit the 'details' rowgroup properties and add a grouping by Practice and ChartGroup (Department and ChartGroup in this example)

In the list box's textbox, right-click then insert a chart.
Set the chart up as required, in my example, I used salary as the values on a pie chart and the employee names as the labels.

Here's the final design ..

[image]

Note that I set the department as a multi-value parameter and also set the number of persons per chart (chartMax) as a report parameter.

When I preview the report I get this for 'Engineering' which has 6 employees

[image]

Sales has 18 employees so we get this

[image]

.... and so on, it will generate a new chart for every 15 people or part thereof.

Comment: Wow, this is useful and amazingly clear. Thank you so much!